# Cannot get jQuery UI Sortable to work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-sortable

I want to have two rows of labels between which you can drag and drop. I just can't get it to work.

I use the following function to initialize my two lists

```
 $("#sortableInit, #sortableEnd").sortable({
   connectWith: "connectedSortable",
   dropOnEmpty: true
  }).disableSelection();
```

Also, one single line of CSS to make them be horizontal instead of the usual vertical (they are both of the class `connectedSortable`) :

```
.connectedSortable > div { float: left; }
```

In the following fiddle I have stripped down what I want to do to the minimum.

http://jsfiddle.net/kuK9x/9/

Can you see something obvious that I am missing ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some syntax error in your javascript panel. (`})` missing at the end)
Another syntax error is `connectWith: "connectedSortable"` should be             `connectWith: ".connectedSortable"`

Also, you should set `.connectedSortable` to `float` too, if not, the height of the container will be zero, which will cause an bug discussed in jQuery. See [ticket#4551](http://bugs.jqueryui.com/ticket/4551#trac-change-4)

See updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kuK9x/10/)

```
$(function () {
    $("#sortableInit, #sortableEnd").sortable({
        connectWith: ".connectedSortable",
        dropOnEmpty: true
    }).disableSelection();
});
```

And CSS

```
.connectedSortable {
    float:left;
}
.connectedSortable > div {
    float: left;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for that. I missed it in the fiddle but didn't in my original webpage.
It still doesn't allow me to drag and drop though right ?

Comment: @Chapo It does for me... I'm using the latest Chrome, also works under IE 10

Comment: Seems like jQuery and jQuery UI websites are down so I can't load the sources on jsFiddle... But it is hosted locally for my webpage and I couldn't get the two sortable objects to connect. Does the "drag-from-one-to-the-other" work properly in your fiddle ?
If it does, I'll validate your answer when I can verify it.

Comment: @Chapo I've updated my answer. Please also check the fiddle `http://jsfiddle.net/kuK9x/10/`

Comment: Thanks that works.
I also got it working by using `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left` within the `.connectedSortable > div {}` instructions. See http://jsfiddle.net/kuK9x/11/